# Apache camel 3.6 how to remove camel http parameters from target HTTP endpoint URL

Tags: http, apache-camel

We are using dynamic URI toD() to invoke HTTP APIs.

.toD("http://localhost:9090/hello-world?httpMethod=GET&httpClient.connectTimeout=7000&httpClient.connectionRequestTimeout=1000")

The camel query parameters (connectTimeout etc) are getting added into target HTTP URL. We want to remove those camel parameters.

Actually it was working with old version 2.x. Recently we migrated to 3.6.x. Post that it started adding these query parameters.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Instead of removing all headers as suggested by @eray_p1 I'd suggest to define an own [HeaderFilterStrategy](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-support/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/support/DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy.java) implementation where you define what HTTP headers are mapped to Camel headers and which Camel Headers are mapped to HTTP headers on receiving or sending HTTP messages

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly , You consuming a camel rest api and then producing an api in Tod method . you must remove headers before toD

```
.removeHeaders("*")
toD("http://localhost:9090/hello-world?httpMethod=GET&httpClient.connectTimeout=7000&httpClient.connectionRequestTimeout=1000")
```

Comment: The removeHeaders(*) did not remove the query string parameter 'httpClient.connectTimeout' & 'httpClient.connectionRequestTimeout'. Looks like still it is sending it to target endpoint.  Our overall goal is remove these two camel parameters & allow other parameters.  Also the connection timeout should work.